# Bash script For Cycle

Tags: bash

i´m new to scripting and bash.
I need help with bash script (for cycle)

I´ve got a script called for.sh
It has to ask 10 numbers from user with for cycle.
In every cycle number will be divided with 3 or 5.
If it divides it will say it.

My idea was to use read, for i in $(eval echo "$numbers") and if commands but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Could you please show us what you've tried to achieve the result?

Comment: By "for cycle" do you mean a ["for loop"](https://study.com/academy/lesson/for-loop-definition-example-results.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by `for` as well as `while` loop.
using `for` loop here:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ ))
do
read -p "Enter the number:" num
if [[ $(($num%3)) -eq '0' ]]
then
echo "$num is divisible by 3"
elif [[ $(($num%5)) -eq '0' ]]
then
echo "$num is divisible by 5"
else
echo "$num is not divisible by either 3 or 5"
fi
done
```

I've initialized a variable `i` to 1, so everytime the `for` loop will run ,it'll ask the number from the user, store it into another variable called `num` and then check if the entered number is divisible by 3 or 5, if the entered number is not divisible by 3 or 5, it will say "number is not divisible by either 3 or 5".

With every run, the `for` loop will increment the count by `1` till it reaches the count=`10`.

Comment: If it has worked for you, you can upvote and accept the answer :-)